Firebase: I am not receiving messages
I have a website and I want to receive notifications through it,
I got the "FCM Token"
But when someone sends me a message, I don't receive the message and I don't know the reason for the problem,
Please help me solve it
firebaseInit.js:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from "firebase/messaging";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCSVOuA-4DT-NGyFXZ5IG13Q7gLpFoMa6Q",
  authDomain: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sookler-plus-a1ef1",
  storageBucket: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "868289122853",
  appId: "1:868289122853:web:803612b64dcb557e04e5cc",
  measurementId: "G-53P05PKSY1"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging(app);

export const onMessageListener = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = onMessage(
      messaging,
      (payload) => {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        resolve(payload);
        unsubscribe();
      },
      (error) => reject(error)
    );
  });
};

export { messaging, getToken, onMessage };

firebase-messaging-sw.js:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"
);
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"
);

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCSVOuA-4DT-NGyFXZ5IG13Q7gLpFoMa6Q",
  authDomain: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "sookler-plus-a1ef1",
  storageBucket: "sookler-plus-a1ef1.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "868289122853",
  appId: "1:868289122853:web:803612b64dcb557e04e5cc",
  measurementId: "G-53P05PKSY1",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  console.log('push:::', event)
  const payload = event.data ? event.data.json() : {};
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification?.title || "New notification";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification?.body || "",
    icon: payload.notification?.icon || "/firebase-logo.png",
  };

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
  );
});

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker installing");
  // Perform install steps, e.g., caching static assets
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("Service worker activating");
  // Perform activation steps, e.g., cleaning up old caches
});

messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("Message received. ", payload);
}); 

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("Received background message ", payload);
  const notificationTitle = payload.notification?.title || "New notification";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification?.body || "",
    icon: payload.notification?.icon || "/firebase-logo.png",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

SigninForm.tsx:
import { getToken, messaging, onMessage } from "../../../firebaseInit";

const SignInForm = ({
  setIsForgotPasswordClick,
  setPhoneNumber,
}: {
  setIsForgotPasswordClick?: any;
  setPhoneNumber?: any;
}) => {
  //location
  const location = useLocation();
  const redirect = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/home";

  //translation
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  //form
  const [loginSchema] = useLoginValidation();

  // LoginModel
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<any>({
    defaultValues: {
      phone: "",
      password: "",
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(loginSchema),
  });

  const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  //redux
  const { message, isOk } = useAppSelector((state) => state.authentication);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [fcmToken, setFcmToken] = useState<any>();
  
  const token: any =
    localStorage.getItem("fcmToken"); 
  console.log("fcccm:", token);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (payload: any) => {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      const notificationTitle =
        payload.notification?.title || "New notification";
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.notification?.body || "",
        icon: payload.notification?.icon || "",
      };

      if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        new Notification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
      }
    };

    const unsubscribe = onMessage(messaging, handleMessage);

    return () => {
      // Clean up listener on unmount
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message?.length > 0) {
      console.log("isOK");
      if (isOk) {
        console.log("isOK");
        dispatch(successModal(message));

        if (token) {
          dispatch(updateToken(token)).then(() => {
            navigate(redirect);
          });
        } else {
          console.error("FCM Token is not available.");
        }
      } else {
        setIsButtonDisabled(false);
        dispatch(errorModal(message));
      }
      dispatch(resetStateStatus());
    }
  }, [message, isOk, dispatch, redirect]);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<LoginModel> = async (data) => {
    setIsButtonDisabled(true);
    dispatch(login(data));
  };

  const handleForgotPassword = () => {
    setIsForgotPasswordClick(true);
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off">
      <Stack direction="column" rowGap="8px" sx={{ width: "100%", mb: "32px" }}>
        <Stack
          direction="column"
          rowGap="16px"
          sx={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "7rem" }}
        >
          <Stack direction="column" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <Controller
              name="phone"
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { name, value, ref, onChange } }) => (
                <GeneralField
                  error={errors.phone}
                  name={name}
                  inputRef={ref}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={(e: any) => {
                    onChange(e);
                    setPhoneNumber(e.target.value); // Update phone number state
                  }}
                  focused={false}
                  inputProps={{
                    maxLength: 10,
                  }}
                  placeholder={t("mobile-number")}
                  icon={MobileIcon}
                />
              )}
            />
            {errors.phone ? <ErrorText errorText={errors.phone.message} /> : ""}
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction="column" rowGap="16px" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <Stack direction="column" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <Controller
                name="password"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { name, value, ref, onChange } }) => (
                  <PasswordField
                    name={name}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={value}
                    inputRef={ref}
                    placeholder={t("password")}
                    focused={false}
                    error={errors.password}
                  />
                )}
              />
              {errors.password ? (
                <ErrorText errorText={errors.password.message} />
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </Stack>
            <HelperText
              secondaryColor="primary.fg2"
              primaryText=""
              secondaryText="forgot-password"
              secondaryTextTransform="capitalize"
              callback={handleForgotPassword}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
        <Stack direction="row" sx={{ width: "100%" }} justifyContent="flex-end">
          <SignButton
            variant="contained"
            type="submit"
            disabled={isButtonDisabled}
          >
            {t("continue")}
          </SignButton>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default SignInForm;

App.tsx:
import { getToken, messaging, onMessageListener } from "./firebaseInit";

function App() {
  const content = useRoutes(routes);
  const [title] = useHeadTitle();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestPermission = async () => {
      try {
        const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
        if (permission === "granted") {
          console.log("Notification permission granted.");
          const token = await getToken(messaging, {
            vapidKey:
              "BG-qtMNhGMcses3C612MtjKQZ9cbonJMI6pbQ4ec47jxtAjaQHepQvL45cANy_18B3I1xRP5WEi7mMvbCc3EnW0",
          });
          console.log("FCM token App:", token);
          if (token) {
            console.log("FCM Token:", token);
             localStorage.setItem("fcmToken", token);
            // Save the token to your server or local storage if needed
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Notification permission denied.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting FCM token:", error);
      }
    };

    requestPermission();

    onMessageListener()
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log("Message received.", payload);
        const notificationTitle =
          payload.notification?.title || "New notification";
        const notificationOptions = {
          body: payload.notification?.body || "",
          icon: payload.notification?.icon || "",
        };

        if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
          new Notification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error handling message:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        try {
          const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
            "/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
            { scope: "/" }
          );
          if (registration.installing) {
            console.log("Service worker installing");
          } else if (registration.waiting) {
            console.log("Service worker installed");
          } else if (registration.active) {
            console.log("Service worker active");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Service Worker registration failed: ${error}`);
        }
      }
    };

    registerServiceWorker();
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <HelmetProvider>
          <Helmet>
            <title>{title}</title>
          </Helmet>
          <MainLayout>{content}</MainLayout>
        </HelmetProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

package.json:
{
  "name": "sookler",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.17.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.10.7",
    "@firebase/messaging": "^0.12.10",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.35",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.1",
    "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player": "^3.5.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.137",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.14.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.10.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.10.2",
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.11.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "compressorjs": "^1.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "firebase": "^10.12.5",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.15.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "i18next": "^23.4.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mui-one-time-password-input": "^1.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-verification-code-input": "^1.2.9",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
    "swiper": "^8.4.7",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}


How are you sending the message? Could you also include the code snippets?

i send message from backend, and the message reach to flutter application, i get this problem just in frontend section.

three possibilities that might help:

try passing your SW registration when you get token

    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
    const currentToken = await getToken(messagingInstance!, {
         vapidKey: "my-key",
         serviceWorkerRegistration: registration
    });


your debug session had an old web worker installed make sure you unregister all web workers using chrome dev tools after every change you do to the SW file and then refresh

in my service worker firebase handles all the events (I dont need to specify things like on message or listen for push event) - I didnt need to handle any except onBackgroundMessage -  your handlers might be taking over and are only console logging - remove them or maybe add self.registration.showNotification(...) to the end - but this is just a guess since I didn't need them


